# Not a valid Win32 application

Tags: c#, windows, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm a complete beginner on C#. I made a simple program using Visual Basic 2013 (Win7 64-bit). When I try to open it on Win XP 32-bit, i get a message ".... not a valid Win32 application". How to fix it?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 3):

- Make sure the Win XP machine has the correct version of the .NET framework installed
- Compile your program to run on all machines not just 64-bit.

To do the second one, right click on the project -> properties -> build -> find the field that says Platform and make sure it says Any CPU (or at least x86)

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the build to AnyCPU in Visual Studio build configuration.

[image: Any CPU]

Comment: Already done that, but still no use :/ Another thing is: When I (on my 64bit pc) open the program folder/bin i see debug, release, x64, x86. When i open the program from the x64 folder, it starts the correct program (the one I've made). When i do it from x86 folder - it opens an almost empty form with a button and a textbox (not the one I've made). Same thing happens when i open from the debug folder.

Comment: How did you solve? I got same problem.If you can share that would be appreciated.

Comment: @Zgrkpnr He build the application in x86 mode this will work with Windows XP x64(WOW) and x86 do not Forget to vote if this will solve your Problem :-)

Comment: @BassamAlugili I will give it a try and give you a feedback

Answer (score 2):

Notice that that in Visual Studio you can target the the .net framework in the build properties.
XP works only with .net 4.0 so you should make sure that you target the build to that framework (I think that it automatically chooses the .net that your OS is running while building the first time).

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a 64 bit program on a 32 bit OS.  You can run a 32 bit program on a 64 bit OS though.  Make sure to target "Any CPU" when compiling the OS.  Project > Properties > Build

Answer (score 0):

Well - you said it yourself. You have created a Win64 application, and sadly enough that´s not the same as a Win32 application...
Build it as "any cpu", and the problem is gone :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your .Net versions are the same on both machines. When you compile the code, check your target framework settings.